# Uniqueness for measure valued ode

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, stochastic-processes

Morning! Basically I'm working on a mean field scaling for some measure valued process (valued on $M_F(\mathbb{N})$). The limit turns up as a (deterministic) solution to a measure valued ODE. Let's say, given a bounded real valued function $f$ :

$$ d\langle\mu_t,f\rangle = \langle\Psi(\mu_t),f\rangle dt$$

where

$$ \langle\Psi(\mu_t),f\rangle = - \frac{\langle\mu_t,\chi^2-\chi\rangle}{\langle\mu_t,\chi\rangle}\frac{\langle\mu_t,\chi\Delta f\rangle}{\langle\mu_t,\chi\rangle} - \frac{\langle\mu_t,\chi f\rangle}{\langle\mu_t,\chi\rangle}$$
with $\chi(k) = k$ and $\Delta f(k) = f(k) - f(k-1)$

My problem arises when I try to show uniqueness for this ODE. Usually, I would just upper bound the total variation distance between two solutions with same initial state and use Gronwall's Lemma to show said distance is null. This time it is delicate since $\Psi(\cdot)$ contains first and second order moments of $\mu_.$. Ie for two solutions $\mu_t$ and $\nu_t$ we end up with
$$d|\langle\mu_t - \nu_t,f\rangle| \leq C||f|| ( |\langle\mu_t - \nu_t,\chi^2\rangle | + |\langle\mu_t  - \nu_t,\chi\rangle | + |\langle\mu_t  - \nu_t,1\rangle |)$$

Whereas the ideal would be to have a multiple of $|\langle\mu_t - \nu_t,f\rangle| $ on the right side. Now, using the EDO to bound $|\langle\mu_t - \nu_t,\chi^2\rangle| $ also fails since it involves the 3rd moment and so on.

My question is: Is there any way to bound $\langle\mu_t - \nu_t,\chi\rangle$ and $\langle\mu_t - \nu_t,\chi^2\rangle$ by some multiple of $d_{TV}(\mu_t,\nu_t)$? Do I have to try another method (suggestions are welcome)?

Additionally both $\langle\mu_t,1\rangle$ and $\langle\mu_t,\chi\rangle$ are both decreasing and bounded, and $\langle\mu_t - \nu_t,\chi^2\rangle$ is finite.

Comment: If, as I presume given that you used the "probability" tag, the measures are actually probability measures: How about trying to use the quadratic Wasserstein distance $W_2$? This seems very appropriate, since $W_2$ controls second moments by construction. In particular $W_2(\mu_t,\nu_t)$ controls $|m_2(\mu_t)-m_2(\nu_t)|$ (the difference between second moments)

Comment: Ah, my bad, I just noticed that $<\mu_t,1>$ is increasing, so you're dealing with  measures with arbitrary and varying masses... Then I can suggest using "unbalanced optimal transport"

Comment: Related to "unbalanced optimal transport" and relatives: I suggest you check the following paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.05105

Comment: First, thank you for your help! Actually, you can have an equivalent problem with $$\<mu_t,1>$$ decreasing so I believe we can state the problem in terms of optimal transport.
I realise the problem was poorly formulated. Actually the biggest problem I encountered with the Wasserstein metric was that the edo terms contained like : $$<\mu_t,\chi \Delta f>$$ and $$<\mu_t,\chi f>$$ so that controling the second moment implies dealing with the third, etc etc

Comment: Wait, now I'm confused: who's $f$ and who's $\chi$? I had the impression that $f$ was an arbitrary test-function, but I'm not too sure anymore.

Comment: Now I see how badly written my statement is, sorry for my english. $f$ is a test function and $\chi$ is just the typical function such that $\chi(x) = x$, it also means that the first moment is expressed as $<\mu_t,\chi>$.
Basically, we have a measure valued ode which involves $$d<\mu_t - \nu_t,f> = ... + <\mu_t - \nu_t,\chi f> $$
So that for example, bounding $m_2$ will imply using $m_3$

Comment: Which domain are you working on? is $N$ bounded? in Euclidean spaces if the domain is bounded as $|x|\leq R,\, x\in N$ then the $p$-th momment can be trivially controlled as $m_p(f)-m_p(g)=\int |x|^p d(f-g)\leq R^p \int |x/R|^pd(f-g)\leq R^p d_{TV}(f,g)$ (and by symmetry you control the absolute value).

Comment: Regardless of the English language (which is fine, don't worry!): unless you give us the means to grasp  the sublte technical details of your problem by clarifying the notations, the setting etc. I doubt that we can help you as is. For example: perhaps it is worth wrting down explicitly the formula defining your "vector-field" $\Psi(\mu)$?

Comment: Really thank you for your patience. I was a newbie both on the site and on LateX. I've edited the problem to be more specific and I tried to add context.

Comment: I guess you don't have any additional information on the decay/support of your measures arising from some other features of the problem? If you knew for example that $(\mu_t)^i$ was rapidly decaying in $i\in\mathbb{N}$ at a uniform rate, then you would be in business right?